# In a nosql database like MongoDB or Couchbase how to model many to many relationship?

Tags: mongodb, many-to-many, couchbase

Consider a scenario of an application where I have users and projects and the requirement is users shall be assigned to projects. One user can be assigned to multiple projects. This is a many to many relationship. So what is the best way to model such a requirement.

I will like to discuss few approaches to model such a requirement :

**- Embeded data model**

In this approach I will embedd the user documents inside projects document.

Advantages : you get all the required data in one API call OR by fetching one single document.

Disadvantages : Data duplicacy which is OK

```
            Real problem is if you update user information for eg user mobile no or name from users screen then this updated information should also be reflected under all embedded user documents. For this some bulk update query should be fired.
```

*But is this the right way ???*

**- Embedding object references instead of objects (which is normalised)**

In this case if we embedd user id's instead of user objects then the problem mentioned above wont be there but then we will have to make multiple network calls to get required data or make a seperate relation kond of document as we do in SQL.

*Is this the best way ??*

Comment: I dont think this should be stackoverflow question. It should go to [Database Administration StackExchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This isn't a administration question, it's an app data design question.

Answer (score 0):

We have a same scenario, so i embed objectId. and for fill data for clients, populate users data in find function.

```
    contract.find({}).populate('user').then(function(){});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few hard and fast rules, but usually with many-to-many relationships you would prefer references over embedding.  This doesn't mean your data is totally flat/normalized.

For example, you could have a user document with an array of project ids.  You could have the reverse for projects.

Think about your queries and how you will structure them.  That can give you other hints about how to structure your documents.

Comment: One resource I like for understanding basic data modeling with NoSQL is a video by Microsoft entitled "Modeling Data for NoSQL Document Databases".  There are several copies of it uploaded on YouTube.